# Register default object mapper as primary in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to use the default ObjectMapper almost everywhere in my application. However, there is a specific request that I need to sent to a third party that requires different ObjectMapper.

There are lots of posts on how to customize the default mapper, but I was not able to find a single one explaining how to add an ObjectMapper without replacing the default one.

I tried adding @Qualifier, adding a name to the @Bean, even creating a new class that subclasses ObjectMapper, to no avail. As soon as I add any kind of ObjectMapper, the default one always gets replaced.

[image]

[image]

Can someone provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: Please, add code snippets showing your best try, questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @LMC I have added the snippets of what i am trying to do.

Comment: you have added images, not codesnippets. Try changing the autowired attribute name to `customObjMapper`